# Schur complement counter example?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think I may be getting mixed up with some terms, but for positive definite matrices "$X$ is positive definite if and only if $A$ and $X/A$ are both positive definite", can't we take $A = 1$, $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1000, & 1000, & 1000\end{bmatrix},$ $C= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \text{ ?}$ Then $X$ would contain strictly positive entries but $X/A$ is not positive definite.

Note, I noticed that my $C$ has to be invertible...

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: Your $C$ is nonnegative-definite but not strictly positive-definite.

Comment: What is $X$? Kindly edit the question to include more information.